# Multiple table with same class name in HTML parsing using lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am working on lxml for fetching the html page.
I want to fetch the html table which have the class name as 'class1'.
I have done something like this :

```
for span in doc.xpath('//table[@class="class1"]'):
print span
```

But,
after this I found that there are 4 tables in HTML page which have class name as 'class1'.
for example :

```
table A
table B
table C
table D
```

these all 4 tables have the same class name.
how I can fetch only table B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the second item of list:

```
result = doc.xpath('//table[@class="class1"]')
if len(result) > 1:
  print result[1]
```

Or if your table has id, you can get it via xpath:

```
print doc.xpath('//table[@id="you id"]')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might want here is...

```
doc.xpath('//table[@class="class1"]')[1]
```